# How to publishing a Vensim model via code.

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, simulation, modeling

I'm working with visual studio 2010 in the C # language. I want to publish a model using code (dll from [Vensim](http://vensim.com/) DSS) and not using the GUI of Vensim DSS. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible via any code. The reason for publishing is to ensure that a licensed copy of Vensim DSS is used to generate the model.

Comment: Had earlier given me an answer (http://www.ventanasystems.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5065). But if i have Vensim DSS, why could not publish many models dynamically?